# How to generate g.dart file in flutter while using redux?

Tags: flutter, dart, redux

I'm facing the issue of generating a g.dart file in a flutter. 
Can anyone show step by step guide for same? Or the easiest way to do that.

How to create a model with .g.dart file in flutter-redux-starter?

More about flutter-redux-starter

https://github.com/hillelcoren/flutter-redux-starter

Help Appreciated.